# Does flat band imply localization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, topological-insulators, topological-phase

Consider the Kitaev chain, whose Hamiltonian is as follows:

$$ H = -\mu \sum_n c_n^\dagger c_n -t\sum_n (c_n^\dagger c_{n+1} + \mathrm{h.c.}) +\Delta \sum_n (c_n c_{n+1} + \mathrm{h.c.}) $$

I have some questions concerning the 'localization' of the modes. The localization here has nothing to do with disorder.

If we set $\mu = 0$, $\Delta = t = 1$, the Hamiltonian has a simple form. Introducing Majorana operators so that $c_n = a_n + i b_n$,$c_n^\dagger = a_n - ib_n$, we can write the Hamiltonian as:

$$H = -4i \sum_n b_n a_{n+1} $$

We can see that the modes are strictly local. On the other hand, setting $ \Delta = t = 0$ while $\mu = 1$ will also give a sets of local modes:

$$ H = -\sum_n c_n^{\dagger} c_n$$

We can view the occupation of these local modes as local integrals of motion. In more general parameter regimes, those occupation operators will be non-local integrals of motion.

My question is, how can one determine when will a non-interacting fermionic Hamiltonian have local integrals of motion as described above? I noticed that under these specific regimes of parameters the energy band is flat. Is it generally true that when one has a flat band Hamiltonian one can find a set of integrals of motion that is local?